# How can I optimize this script so it does not take a week to finish the task it is doing? (Used BASH PARALLEL too.)

Tags: python, bash, csv, argparse, rdkit

I have a directory full of 60,000 files that are named by their molid. I have a second file in CSV format that has molids in column 1 with their respective CHEMBLID in column 2. I need to match the file name molid in the directory with a molid in the CSV file. If a match is found, the chemblid is added to the file (the file is rewritten to have the chemblid included). I am also using RDKit to calculate some properties I need written to the modified file too. I need to find a way to optimize this since I have to run it on 2 million files soon.

The way I am interacting with arg parse is by listing all of the molid.sdf files in my directory with the bash parallel command.

The csv file looks like:

```
molid,chembl
319855,CHEMBLtest
187481,CHEMBL1527718
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ynd9vbwwf6lqka/output_2.csv?dl=0

The file that needs to be modified looks like:

```
298512 from gamess16 based ATb pipeline
 OpenBabel06141815083D

 34 35  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    4.3885   -1.0129    1.6972 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.3885   -0.7157    0.5784 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6479   -1.5425   -0.5699 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4599    0.7380    0.1087 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.4770    1.0889   -1.0314 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0165    0.9826   -0.6438 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.3679    2.0729    0.0029 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.9531    1.9980    0.3853 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.7151    0.8214    0.1489 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.0800    0.7051    0.5321 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.8067   -0.4453    0.2969 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.2581   -0.5636    0.6988 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.1581   -1.5376   -0.3496 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8397   -1.4605   -0.7357 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0762   -0.2830   -0.5007 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.2871   -0.1675   -0.8844 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1834   -0.3978    2.5815 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.4123   -0.8100    1.3616 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3301   -2.0654    2.0016 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.3709   -0.9175    0.9451 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4809   -2.4622   -0.3076 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.2757    1.3897    0.9729 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.4830    0.9450   -0.2346 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6837    0.4273   -1.8785 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6901    2.1132   -1.3637 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.9314    2.9850    0.1903 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.4318    2.8450    0.8726 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5539    1.5524    1.0253 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.9075   -0.6633   -0.1810 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.4288   -1.4505    1.3221 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.5904    0.3146    1.2616 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.7228   -2.4486   -0.5381 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.3620   -2.3059   -1.2268 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7671   -1.0133   -1.3738 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1 19  1  0  0  0  0
  1 17  1  0  0  0  0
  2 20  1  1  0  0  0
  2  1  1  0  0  0  0
  3 21  1  0  0  0  0
  3  2  1  0  0  0  0
  4  2  1  0  0  0  0
  4 22  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  4  1  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  7 26  1  0  0  0  0
  7  8  2  0  0  0  0
  8 27  1  0  0  0  0
  9  8  1  0  0  0  0
  9 10  2  0  0  0  0
 10 28  1  0  0  0  0
 11 10  1  0  0  0  0
 11 12  1  0  0  0  0
 12 31  1  0  0  0  0
 12 30  1  0  0  0  0
 13 11  2  0  0  0  0
 14 15  2  0  0  0  0
 14 13  1  0  0  0  0
 15  9  1  0  0  0  0
 16  6  2  0  0  0  0
 16 15  1  0  0  0  0
 18  1  1  0  0  0  0
 23  4  1  0  0  0  0
 24  5  1  0  0  0  0
 25  5  1  0  0  0  0
 29 12  1  0  0  0  0
 32 13  1  0  0  0  0
 33 14  1  0  0  0  0
 34 16  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <molid>
298512

$$$$
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r9kandkbahgexj/298512.sdf?dl=0

And a modified file with how the current script works looks like:

```
298512 from gamess16 based ATb pipeline
     RDKit          3D

 34 35  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    4.3885   -1.0129    1.6972 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.3885   -0.7157    0.5784 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6479   -1.5425   -0.5699 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4599    0.7380    0.1087 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.4770    1.0889   -1.0314 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0165    0.9826   -0.6438 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.3679    2.0729    0.0029 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.9531    1.9980    0.3853 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.7151    0.8214    0.1489 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.0800    0.7051    0.5321 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.8067   -0.4453    0.2969 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.2581   -0.5636    0.6988 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.1581   -1.5376   -0.3496 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8397   -1.4605   -0.7357 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0762   -0.2830   -0.5007 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.2871   -0.1675   -0.8844 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1834   -0.3978    2.5815 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.4123   -0.8100    1.3616 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3301   -2.0654    2.0016 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.3709   -0.9175    0.9451 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4809   -2.4622   -0.3076 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.2757    1.3897    0.9729 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.4830    0.9450   -0.2346 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6837    0.4273   -1.8785 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6901    2.1132   -1.3637 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.9314    2.9850    0.1903 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.4318    2.8450    0.8726 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5539    1.5524    1.0253 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.9075   -0.6633   -0.1810 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.4288   -1.4505    1.3221 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -5.5904    0.3146    1.2616 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.7228   -2.4486   -0.5381 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.3620   -2.3059   -1.2268 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7671   -1.0133   -1.3738 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1 19  1  0
  1 17  1  0
  2 20  1  1
  2  1  1  0
  3 21  1  0
  3  2  1  0
  4  2  1  0
  4 22  1  0
  5  6  1  0
  5  4  1  0
  6  7  1  0
  7 26  1  0
  7  8  2  0
  8 27  1  0
  9  8  1  0
  9 10  2  0
 10 28  1  0
 11 10  1  0
 11 12  1  0
 12 31  1  0
 12 30  1  0
 13 11  2  0
 14 15  2  0
 14 13  1  0
 15  9  1  0
 16  6  2  0
 16 15  1  0
 18  1  1  0
 23  4  1  0
 24  5  1  0
 25  5  1  0
 29 12  1  0
 32 13  1  0
 33 14  1  0
 34 16  1  0
M  END
>  <molid>  (1) 
298512

>  <CHEMBLID>  (1) 
CHEMBL3278713

>  <i_user_TOTAL_CHARGE>  (1) 
0

>  <SMILES>  (1) 
'[H]OC([H])(C([H])([H])[H])C([H])([H])C([H])([H])C1C([H])=C([H])C2=C([H])C(=C([H])C([H])=C2C=1[H])C([H])([H])[H]'

>  <InChI>  (1) 
'InChI=1S/C15H18O/c1-11-3-7-15-10-13(5-4-12(2)16)6-8-14(15)9-11/h3,6-10,12,16H,4-5H2,1-2H3/t12-/m0/s1'

$$$$
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfcmiv7d298s1fl/298512.chembl.sdf?dl=0

```
import os,shutil,csv
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-molid", help="molids from file names", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
fn = args.molid
print(fn)
suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier(fn, removeHs=False, sanitize=False)
ms = [x for x in suppl if x is not None] #sanity check loop to make sure the files were read
print("This is the number of entries read in")
print(len(ms))
print(len(suppl))
w=Chem.SDWriter('totaltest_with_chembl.sdf') #writes new file with all of the chemblid
new_files_with_chembl_id=os.path.splitext(fn)[0]
w=Chem.SDWriter(new_files_with_chembl_id+'.chembl.sdf')


molid_chemblid = open('output_2.csv','r')
csv_f = csv.reader(molid_chemblid)
header = next(csv_f)
molidIndex = header.index("molid")
chemblidIndex = header.index("chembl")
molid_chemblidList = []
for line in csv_f:
    molid = line[molidIndex]
#    print(molid)
    chembl = line[chemblidIndex]
#    print(chembl)
    molid_chemblidList.append([molid,chembl])
    for m in suppl: #molecule in MoleculeSet
        print(m)
        atbname=m.GetProp("_Name")
        fillmein=atbname.split( )[0]
        moleculeCharge=Chem.GetFormalCharge(m)
        smiles_string=Chem.MolToSmiles(m)
        inchi_string=Chem.MolToInchi(m)
        print("molecularCharge")
        print(moleculeCharge)
        print("smile_string")
        print(smiles_string)
        print("inchi string")
        print(inchi_string)
        if fillmein == molid:
        print(chembl)
        print(chembl)
        print(line)
        print("this is line in molid_chemblid",line)
        m.SetProp("CHEMBLID",chembl)
        m.SetProp("i_user_TOTAL_CHARGE",repr(moleculeCharge))
        m.SetProp("SMILES",repr(smiles_string))
        m.SetProp("InChI",repr(inchi_string))
        w.write(m)
```

Comment: The molid in the CSV file sounds like a unique key. Read the CSV file into a map/associative array and loop just once over the files. This reduces the overall effort to roughly 3N where N is the number of files and molids. Your algorithm has a loop within a loop which makes it N*N complexity, which indeed take some time with N=2 million :-) 2 Million files is still a lot and may take between 2 hours and 2 days, depending how big the files are. Running a few threads in parallel will then help, until you I/O saturates.

Comment: Sound advice from @Harald 

Comment: @Harald could you post this as an answer? I have not tried it yet but it makes total sense and will integrate it into my code as soon as I finish working on another script I am making. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The molid in the CSV file sounds like a unique key. Read the CSV file into a map/associative array where the molid is the key and the rest of the row is the value, parsed or not as you need it. Python has builtin CSV parsers with `import csv`.

Then loop just once over the files, find the chemblid by looking up the molid from the file name in the map.

This reduces the overall effort to roughly k*N where N is the number of files and molids and k is a small number.

Your algorithm has a loop within a loop which makes it N*N complexity. This indeed would take some time with N=2 million :-)

2 Million files is still a lot and may take between a few hours and a few days, depending how big the files are, how fast your disk access is and all that. Running a few threads in parallel will then help, until the I/O saturates. But test first, since implementing a parallel approach can get complicated. If you have to get through this only once, it might be ok to wait a bit longer.